# How do I display PDF Pages as thumbnails

Tags: wpf, pdf

I want to display each page in a PDF document as a thumbnail in an WPF list view as images
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need a library that can render the PDF files into images for you. 
If you can afford a commercial library, take a look at [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features), the method [IacDocument.ExportToJPeg_Method](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Amyuni_PDFCreator_IacDocument/Methods/IacDocument.ExportToJPeg_Method.htm) in particular will do what you need (*usual disclaimer applies*).

Just for the record, iTextSharp and PDFSharp will not be able to help you on this task, unless your PDF files are composed by raster images only.